# Docker compose giving invalid command but working when specifying /user/local/bin

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed docker compose by following the usual guide of downloading using curl and giving execute permissions to that file. Issue I’m having is when I try to run docker compose I’m getting invalid command with some permission error. But when I run compose specifying the complete path of the compose file I.e. /usr/local/bin/docker-compose it works with out any issue. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't just say "some permissions error" -- show us the actual error in the text of the question. Also, `type docker-compose` (assuming that your shell is bash) will tell us which version of `docker-compose` is being used when you _don't_ specify `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, how it worked. Adding the user to docker group solved the issue. By the way i was doing all of this in a VM through vagrant script.

```
curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

//Added newly to resolve the permission issue.
usermod -aG docker vagrant
```

Answer (score 0):

A short term solution would be applying `sudo` in front of every docker-compose command.

To fully install docker-compose, you'll need to apply the following steps:

- `DOCKER_CONFIG=${DOCKER_CONFIG:-$HOME/.docker}`

Apply executable permissions to the binary:

- `chmod +x $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose`

or, if you chose to install Compose for all users:

- `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`

Then verify you don't need to use sudo anymore

`docker compose version`

You might also want to try `newgrp docker`

The full installation can be found here (https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/compose-plugin/).

Comment: Why would any of these suggestions make a be necessary only when not using a fully-qualified path?

Comment: (Part of why I ask that: As per the _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), if a question doesn't provide enough detail to allow readers to definitively determine which if any answer is likely to be correct, _it shouldn't be answered at all_).